# How to serve index.html with web api selfhosted with OWIN

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, single-page-application, owin

Should be an easy question, just can't find the answer.

I have an SPA (AngularJS) with web api which is self hosted with Owin. I use Nancy to serve the page, but I would like to get rid of Nancy and use Index.html as my single page.

I've seen this question here: [How to route EVERYTHING other than Web API to /index.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643001/how-to-route-everything-other-than-web-api-to-index-html)

I can't use accepted answer as I don't have MVC and HomeController, the way suggested in the updated question doesn't work either, I get `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://admin.localhost:33333/'.` `No route providing a controller name was found to match request URI 'http://admin.localhost:33333/'`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Move your Index.html to the root of your project. Then `install-package Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles` in Package Manager Console and add the code below:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {

        const string rootFolder = ".";
        var fileSystem=new PhysicalFileSystem(rootFolder);
        var options = new FileServerOptions
                      {
                          EnableDefaultFiles = true,
                          FileSystem = fileSystem
                       };

        app.UseFileServer(options);

    }
}
```

This will serve up your Index.html by default.

You can checkout Scott Allen's blog for more reading:

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/10/building-a-simple-file-server-with-owin-and-katana.aspx

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Just a suggestion: the package seems to be in plural form: Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles

Comment: Can we use this technique to host both UI ( angular app ) and the WebApi in the same port? If yes then can you share the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem where i needed to serve a **single page app (react in my case) and some api controllers from the same self hosted OWIN pipeline**. The accepted answer works great to serve the client files, but it fails if your SPA uses client side routing.

If your SPA needs client side routing (i used react-router-dom), you need to redirect requests that don't map to files or api controllers to your `index.html` file. To do this, you can add a custom middleware at the end of your pipeline and use the `SendFileAsync()` method from [Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles) to return `index.html`:

```cs
public class OwinPipeline
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
        // SPA files from /wwwroot
        var opts = new FileServerOptions
        {
            EnableDefaultFiles = true,
            FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem("./wwwroot"),
        };
        appBuilder.UseFileServer(opts);

        // Web API
        var config = new HttpConfiguration
        {
            IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always
        };
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);

        // Use index.html if not a file or controller route
        appBuilder.Use(async (context, _) =>
        {
            // If no middleware handled the request, send index.html.
            // this way the client side router can handle the route.
            await context.Response.SendFileAsync("./wwwroot/index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

There are two important points here:

1. The middleware needs to be the last one in your pipeline. This way it only gets called when no other middleware matched the request.
2. Don't call `await next()` in your last middleware as this would change the response code to a 404. This is a default behavior of the OWIN pipeline.

Note:

- I placed my `index.html` and all other SPA files in a `wwwroot` folder in my project.
- When you use a relativ path in `SendFileAsync()`, it uses `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` as base path to locate your file. If your web filesystem root differs from that, it throws a FileNotFound exception. In this case it might be necessary to provide the absolute path to your `index.html` file.