# How to efficiently serve static files in .NET?

Tags: .net, http, owin, nancy, static-files

I have searched for solution, and what I found out so far:

1. Hosting static content directly using `nginx` or `iis`. They are built to serve static files efficiently.
2. For `NancyFx` there is a `StaticContentConventionBuilder`
3. For `OWIN` app there is a `StaticFileMiddleware`
4. Custom static handler: stream file from file system per **each** request (with old `etag`) and manually handle `etags`, `last-modified` and `cache-control` headers.

Because of my constraints I can't <s>(or don't want to)</s> use **1-3 options**.

I think **option 4** is not good one (please, correct me, if I'm wrong) because it's **expensive** to operate with file system. So I want to reinvent the wheel and create efficient static content handler (with caching files content in memory, file system watching etc) or find other solutions.

I looked over docs and source code of [managing static content](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Managing-static-content) in `NancyFx` and [StaticFiles](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles/StaticFileContext.cs) in `OWIN`. Both actually are similar to **option 4**. Why are these methods considered to be efficient?

How to efficiently (customly) serve static files in .NET?

Comment: it is confusing when you say you can't use iis. asp.net is hosted within iis, and the file extension dictates which engine the page is served, so if you have a .htm file, then iis won't pass it on to the asp.net engine to process. voila!

Comment: @Jeremy it is owin self hosted app

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28476795/how-to-serve-index-html-with-web-api-selfhosted-with-owin

Comment: *Why are these methods considered to be efficient?* - why do you consider them to be inefficient?

Comment: @tomredfern because it's expensive to operate with file system for each request

Comment: @Jeremy thank you for link. that answer actually is about option #3.

Comment: So, by *efficient* you actually mean cost effective?

Comment: @tomredfern _efficient_ - accomplishing something with little waste. I am sorry, my english is not good enough