# Hosting REACT spa application and REST Web API using OWIN

Tags: react-router, owin

WE want to using OWIN to host both React SPA application and WebAPIs. We are currently using UseFileServer owin middleware to server static file for default route. However, this way, other route of SPA are broken.

Current Startup configuration code :

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            config.EnableCors();
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            IContainer container = ServiceContainerManager.GetServiceContainer();
            // Set the WebApi DependencyResolver
            config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
            app.UseWebApi(config);

            FileServerOptions options = new FileServerOptions()
            {
                RequestPath = PathString.Empty,
                FileSystem = new PhysicalFileSystem(@".\frontend"),
                EnableDefaultFiles = true,
            };

            options.StaticFileOptions.ServeUnknownFileTypes = true;
            options.DefaultFilesOptions.DefaultFileNames = new string[] { "index.html" };

            app.UseFileServer(options);
        }
```

When I access "http://localhost/" it serves the index.html, however, when I access http://localhost/route1 (which is a different route in the same SPA), it doesn't work. Essentially, we expect react routing to cover this route. Any help in this area is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather old questions, but i recently had the some problem and found a solution.

You can add a custom middleware at the end of your pipeline and serve the `index.html` file independent of the request path. This way react-router can handle the route. The middleware will only get executed if the request was not already handled from your fileServer or WebApi middleware since it is at the last position in your pipeline.

```cs
...

// Use index.html if not a file or controller route
appBuilder.Use(async (context, _) =>
{
    // If no middleware handled the request, send index.html.
    // this way the client side router can handle the route.
    await context.Response.SendFileAsync("./frontend/index.html");
});
```

For more details see my answer on [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78206220/1925078)