# Seperate client sources from the server's ones

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to create a web application using C#/MVC5 with the following folder structure, where my client sources are separated from the server's ones

- Controllers

  - HomeController.cs
  - FooApiController.cs
- Client

  - assets ( folder )

    - images ( folder )

      - logo.png
    - font.ttf
  - components ( folder )

    - foo ( folder )

      - fooService.js
  - index.cshtml
  - web.config (EDIT)

I want to be able to call my differents files in the client folder, without the folder 'client',e.g:

```
<img src="assets/images/logo.png" />
```

instead of

```
<img src="client/assets/images/logo.png" />
```

Moreever, I want to route all the others files to client/index.cshtml.
[I though about adding a route like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19643001/how-to-route-everything-other-than-web-api-to-index-html) :

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{*anything}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
);
```

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View("~/client/index.cshtml");
    }
}
```

And adding rules as specified in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149750/using-asp-net-routing-to-serve-static-files) for each folder in my client folder. e.g :

```
<rule name="client" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^assets/?(.*)$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/client/assets/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

The problem with this is that whenever I tried to get my image

```
http://localhost:49312/client/assets/images/logo.png
```

or

```
// returns to http://localhost:49312/client/assets/images/logo.png
http://localhost:49312/assets/images/logo.png
```

I get a 'Ressource not found' error

What is the proper way to go ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out why it wasn't working :
I copied the web.config file from the default Views folder to my client folder.

There was an blocking handler in this file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
       <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
       <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I did everything I said in my initial post plus removing this handler, and it works great now

Answer (score 0):

Have you heard about MVC Areas?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas

http://www.itorian.com/2013/10/area-in-mvc-5-with-example-step-by-step.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: It could have been a solution, but I want to reuse my client sources in a different project ( UWP html/js )